# How to copy to system clipboard using Mosh + Tmux?

Tags: neovim, cut-copy-paste, ssh

I've set `vim.opt.clipboard = "unnamedplus"` to copy to/paste from the system clipboard. However, I noticed that the behavior differs whether I'm using `nvim` in my local machine, a remote machine via `ssh`, or a remote machine via `mosh`.

Specifically, I can copy to the local clipboard and paste from the local clipboard, in a local machine using `yy` and `p`.

In a remote machine via `ssh`, I can copy text to the local clipboard
with `yy` but paste only with `Cmd-v` (my local machine is a MacBook).

On a remote machine via `mosh`, nothing seems to work, including `"*yy` and `"+yy`. Is there a solution, or is this feature not available with Mosh?

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on the server with X11 and `tmux`. The local Machine is a MacBook with MacOS 14 and `iTerm2`.